# send the API key through Apigee

Tags: api, key, apigee

My manager asked me if we can send the API key to our customers(developers in our client companies) through Apigee with formal and secured way. I checked the online documentation and couldn't find the information regarding to sending API key via Apigee.
Any one please provide more information on that?

Answer (score 0):

Every Apigee Edge Org has a developer portal associated with it. This developer portal can be used by the developers to register themselves and create application and get the Api Keys.

You can provide the Url of the developer portal to the developers in your client companies and ask them to register on the developer portal and create apps to get api keys.

Please find the links to the documentation related to developer portal and how to get a developer portal for your organization.

http://apigee.com/docs/developer-services/content/what-developer-portal

http://apigee.com/docs/content/creating-developer-portal

Regards,
Sudheesh